# How to filter array of array data based on certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

In a React project, I've data filled in a table which is in the format of array of array. For array of objects is quite easy to manipulate but difficult in array of array data. Here I want to filter based on specific condition and return it with new array. Please refer below code for clarity

Below is the data to be manipulated

```
const newArrayData = [
    [
      { id: 1 },
      false,
      "McDonalds",
      "Burger Store",
      "Mike John",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Food Chain"
    ],
    [
      { id: 2 },
      false,
      "KFC",
      "Chicken Food Store",
      "Rock Wills",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Food Chain Globally"
    ],
    [
      { id: 3 },
      false,
      "KFC",
      "Chicken Food Store",
      "Sam",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Food Chain Globally"
    ],
    [
      { id: 4 },
      false,
      "KFC",
      "Chicken Food Store",
      "Amir",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Food Chain Globally"
    ],
    [
      { id: 5 },
      false,
      "Starbucks",
      "Coffee Store",
      "Stephen",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Coffee"
    ],
    [
      { id: 6 },
      false,
      "McDonals",
      "Burger Store",
      "Mark",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Food Chain Globally"
    ]
  ];
```

Here I'm intergating into the Grid

```
// I want to filter out KFC and return new array and pass to grid
const dataNew = newArrayData.filter((data) => data === "KFC");

const store_grid_data = {
    data: dataNew,
    page_info: {
      total_pages: 5,
      current_page: 1
    }
  };
let GridConfig = {};
  let grid_data = {};

  GridConfig = TableConfig;
  grid_data = store_grid_data;

  const [gridConfigData, setGridConfigData] = useState(GridConfig);
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState(grid_data);

  return (
    <>
      <Grid GridConfig={gridConfigData} GridData={gridData} />
    </>
  );
```

As you can see from above code, I have tried to filter with the logic above but it returns empty data. What is the best solution to tackle this?
Please refer to the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-boyd-2e16j6

Comment: is KFC always in 3rd position if so `data[2]==='KFC'`  else `data.includes('KFC')`

Comment: Suggestion: Try using better structure. Instead of array of array of object or string, have only object. That will add context as to what each value is and will simplify usage

Comment: Thanks for the response.... if you don't mind can you update to codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

look at this code..

```
const dataNew = newArrayData.filter((data) =>{} );
```

the data in filter method actually is an array and U must iterate data to check it includes "kfc" or not. kile this:

```
 const dataNew = newArrayData.filter((data) =>{data.includes("KFC")} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I implement a workaround using for loop:

```
const Table = () => {
  const newArrayData = [
    [
      { id: 1 },
      false,
      "McDonalds",
      "Burger Store",
      "Mike John",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Food Chain"
    ],
    [
      { id: 2 },
      false,
      "KFC",
      "Chicken Food Store",
      "Rock Wills",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Food Chain Globally"
    ],
    [
      { id: 3 },
      false,
      "KFC",
      "Chicken Food Store",
      "Sam",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Food Chain Globally"
    ],
    [
      { id: 4 },
      false,
      "KFC",
      "Chicken Food Store",
      "Amir",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Food Chain Globally"
    ],
    [
      { id: 5 },
      false,
      "Starbucks",
      "Coffee Store",
      "Stephen",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Coffee"
    ],
    [
      { id: 6 },
      false,
      "McDonals",
      "Burger Store",
      "Mark",
      "YYYY/MM",
      "Best Food Chain Globally"
    ]
  ];

  const dataNew = []
  for (let index in newArrayData) {
    if (newArrayData[index].includes('KFC')) dataNew.push(newArrayData[index])
  }
```